# Flash Builder intellisense - Unable to detect members of class randomly

Tags: eclipse, ide, compiler-errors, flash-builder

Suddenly flash builder stops identifying data members of a class. When I type obj. the intellisense window does not show any data members or methods. Yesterday I got problem with 4.6 and now with 4.0. Yesterday I imported the source files into new project to resolve this problem. I thought it is something to do with the newer version but I got this in 4.0 as well. This is really a huge problem.

I did all tries like

Reopening project
Restarting FB
Triple checking the import packages/classes
Syntax error

It is similar problem with many of people got here and I am sure it is not a problem of importing packages/classes or any syntax because It happens all the sudden randomly to random class.

Not just that but when I ctl+click on the variable (which should tame cursor to the variable declaration) IDE throws an error message "Code Navigation error: Source could not be found"

I am not pasting any code here because, as I said earlier I am sure its not related to any syntax, importing issue (in short not a coding isssue), but just some sort of FBs memeory/stack or something else.

Please let me know if any one has faced this problem and found the solution other than copying the source into a new project

Comment: Try bumping up the memory in <flash builder install dir>/eclipse/eclipse.ini. Change -Xmx512m to -Xmx1024m.

Comment: Also, intellisense often won't work if there are any other compile errors.

Comment: @jalynn2 i guess its FlashBuilder.ini in install dir, I changed it, still no use. BTW its did not imported huge libraries, neither my project has more than 2 classes